# React - can a component be styled depending on what other component is rendered?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have a Search component, when the homepage component is rendered I'd like the Search component to be rendered at the bottom of the page. When any other page component is rendered I'd like the Search component to be at the top of the page.

Currently what I have my app.js as:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/work' component={Work} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

and inside a page component:

```
const Contact = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Search />
        Contact
      </div>
    )
}
```

Obviously this way means I have to add the Search component to every component and choose whether I place it at the top or bottom.

My question is this, can I place it on the app.js like so:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Search />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/work' component={Work} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

And then depending on which page component is being rendered, style the Search component so it either appears at the top or bottom of the page.

Thanks

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `className` prop to the Search component and add some if statement.
For example:

```
<Search className={location === '/' ? 'top' : 'bottom'} />
```

Comment: Thanks for this, have been playing around with it and I keep getting the error: 
TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined
I'm not using TypeScript in this project.
I'm using the useLocation in the App.js file however, not within each seperate component, Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: @Cal why don't you want to use this hook in each separate file? there's no problem. hooks are made for this.

Comment: In my mind, putting the Search component within each of the other components (Home, About, Work and Contact), was a bit unnecessary. I was trying to find a way of only using the Search component once, in the App.js outside the Switch. And then depending on which page component is rendered it would either display at the top or bottom. Using useLocation on the Search component in each seperate file, whilst admittedly is useful and I'll be using elsewhere, doesn't address my original question. Thanks again though for showing me useLocation as it's super cool!

Answer (score 1):

With the `useLocation()` hook provided by React Router, you can determine what page you're on.

```js
const Contact () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const styles = location === "something" ? {...topStyles} : {...downStyles};

  return (
    <div>
      <Search style={styles} />
      Contact
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, have been playing around with it and I keep getting the error: 
TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined
I'm not using TypeScript in this project however.
I'm using the useLocation in the App.js file however, not within each seperate component, as you had shown above. Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: @Cal It might be (not sure though) that the BrowserRouter or Switch component is providing the context, so when using using the hook outside of those, that it can't find the context. Or am I misunderstanding the problem?
In any case, I don't really see any reason to place Search outside of the page components. It's not unthinkable you'll eventually need a page without it.